# Can any machine learning algorithm find this pattern: x1 < x2 without generating a new feature (e.g. x1-x2) first?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, pattern-recognition

If I had 2 features x1 and x2 where I know that the pattern is:

```
if x1 < x2 then 
    class1 
else 
    class2
```

Can any machine learning algorithm find such a pattern? What algorithm would that be?

I know that I could create a third feature x3 = x1-x2. Then feature x3 can easily be used by some machine learning algorithms. For example a decision tree can solve the problem 100% using x3 and just 3 nodes (1 decision and 2 leaf nodes).

But, is it possible to solve this without creating new features? This seems like a problem that should be easily solved 100% if a machine learning algorithm could only find such a pattern.

I tried MLP and SVM with different kernels, including svg kernel and the results are not great. As an example of what I tried, here is the scikit-learn code where the SVM could only get a score of 0.992:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVC

# Generate 1000 samples with 2 features with random values
X_train = np.random.rand(1000,2)

# Label each sample. If feature "x1" is less than feature "x2" then label as 1, otherwise label is 0.
y_train = X_train[:,0] < X_train[:,1]
y_train = y_train.astype(int) # convert boolean to 0 and 1

svc = SVC(kernel = "rbf", C = 0.9) # tried all kernels and C values from 0.1 to 1.0

svc.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("SVC score: %f" % svc.score(X_train, y_train))
```

Output running the code:

```
SVC score: 0.992000
```

This is an oversimplification of my problem. The real problem may have hundreds of features and different patterns, not just x1 < x2. However, to start with it would help a lot to know how to solve for this simple pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand this, you must go into the settings of all the parameters provided by `sklearn`, and `C` in particular. It also helps to understand how the value of `C` influences the classifier's training procedure.

If you look at the equation in the [User Guide for SVC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svc), there are two main parts to the equation - the first part tries to find a small set of weights that solves the problem, and the second part tries to minimize the classification errors.

`C` is the penalty multiplier associated with misclassifications. If you decrease `C`, then you reduce the penalty (lower training accuracy but better generalization to test) and vice versa.

Try setting `C` to `1e+6`. You will see that you *almost always* get 100% accuracy. The classifier has learnt the pattern x1 < x2. But it figures that a 99.2% accuracy is enough when you look at another parameter called `tol`. This controls how much error is negligible for you and by default it is set to `1e-3`. If you reduce the tolerance, you can also expect to get similar results.

In general, I would suggest you to use something like `GridSearchCV` ([link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html)) to find the optimal values of hyper parameters like `C` as this internally splits the dataset into train and validation. This helps you to ensure that you are not just tweaking the hyperparameters to get a good training accuracy but you are also making sure that the classifier will do well in practice.